# Unable to create simple console.log nodejs snap from github

Tags: snap, ubuntu-core, nodejs

Before I start creating a snap from my real application, I thought it be a good idea to start with a simple console.log app. However.....after two days I'm getting nowhere :(

I'm running **Ubuntu Core** (16.04) and I've created a small GitHub repo at https://github.com/wmmihaa/wmmihaa001.

These are the steps I followed:

**1** I created a folder called wmmihaa001 (same as repo) and ran the following comand in classic mode:

```
sudo snapcraft init
```

**2** This created a **snap** folder with the snapcraft.yaml file that I edited:

```
name: wmmihaa001
version: '0.1' 
summary: ...
description: |
  ...
grade: devel 
confinement: devmode 
parts:
  wmmihaa001:
    source: https://github.com/wmmihaa/wmmihaa001.git
    plugin: nodejs
apps:
  hello:
    command: bin/hello-wmmihaa
```

(the command correlates with my package.json):

```
...
"bin": {
  "hello-wmmihaa": "index.js"
},
...
```

**3** Next I build the project using:

```
snapcraft
```

which outputted in:

```
Staging wmmihaa001
Priming wmmihaa001
Snapping 'wmmihaa001' /
Snapped wmmihaa001_0.1_amd64.snap
```

**4** Lastly, I installed the project using:

```
sudo snap install --devmode wmmihaa001_0.1_amd64.snap
```

which returned:

```
wmmihaa001 0.1 installed
```

**5** I check that my snap was installed using *snap list*, and sure enough, it's there:

```
wmmihaa001            0.1              x1               devmode
```

**6** I exit classic mode and run **wmmihaa001.hello**:

```
admin@dell3001:~/snap$ wmmihaa001.hello
/snap/wmmihaa001/x1/bin/hello-wmmihaa: 1: /snap/wmmihaa001/x1/bin/hello-wmmihaa: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")
admin@dell3001:~/snap$
```

The only syntax in the file is:

```
console.log("Hello WMMIHAA");
```

Also... Sometimes after I've built the snap it doesn't get created in the ../snap folder where I can find other snaps I've build from existing samples